# Connection refuse for mongo macos

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-catalina

Whenever I try to execute the command `mongo` from my terminal, this errors pops up:

```sh
MongoDB shell version v4.4.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:362:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I've been following [this](https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html) tutorial in order to install mongo on my MacBook Pro and failed by creating the `/data/db`. Later, [this](https://medium.com/@semmons245/arghhhh-thanks-to-the-catalina-os-update-this-now-needs-changing-987f416ebcbe) other article appeared upon me. The second one orders me to run the next piece of code from my terminal:

```sh
mongo — dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

But the same error that I pasted at the begining appears.

Is there anything I can do to install and keep mongo running?

**OS:** macOS Catalina - 10.15.16

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like a typo in that blog.  the command should probably have been `mongod --dbpath ...`

Comment: @Joe That way it throws a: `Invalid command: —-dbpath`

Comment: You can also refer these [Install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) tutorial (pick the appropriate one) and verify your installation, startup and connecting with `mongo` shell.

Comment: I started with that one and it leaded me to the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try to:

```
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 1):

For macOS user：

1、reinstall mongodb-community

```sh
brew uninstall mongodb-community
brew cleanup
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

2、config and start

```sh
sudo mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
brew services start mongodb-community
```